# C# way to use Objects by reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to figure out this piece of ASP.NET C# code. Can someone suggest what am I not doing right here?

When I run the code below I'm expecting strDest to be "New value" and nDest equal to 2, but they remain unchanged...

```
//These are two variables to fill
string strDest = "";
int nDest = 0;

public enum MyDataType
{
    MyTypeString,
    MyTypeInt
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyDataType type;
    public Object objDest;

    public MyStruct(MyDataType tType, Object oDest)
    {
        type = tType;
        objDest = oDest;
    }
}

//Pass variables by reference
MyStruct[] data2Check = {
    new MyStruct(MyTypeString, strDest),
    new MyStruct(MyTypeInt, nDest),
};

//And set them
for(int i = 0; i < data2Check.Length; i++)
{
    if(data2Check[i].type == MyTypeString)
    {
        (string)data2Check[i].objDest = "New value";
    }
    else if(data2Check[i].type == MyTypeInt)
    {
        (int)data2Check[i].objDest = 2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
OK, Let me re-phrase it. Say, I have a set of variables or members of a class, say 50 of them. They are all of different types. (In this example they are represented by string strDest and int nDest.) OK. Now I also have a two dimensional array of name=value pairs, so each of those pairs should be assigned to my class members depending on the "name". I do the process of determining which "name" goes to what member of the class, and the for() loop below is my abstraction of the assignment process. What seems to be missing is the way to pass my class members by reference into this for() loop so that I can later assign values to them.

PS. So far, none of the examples below do the job...

Comment: Are you running this after a postback? Do you realize that you're working with a brand new instance of your page class for each postback/event, rather than the same instance?

Comment: Also, your code sample doesn't show where you observe the result, or what you expect to observe vs what you actually observe.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with postback or not. It's all in one function. It's the C# language. As you can probably tell I'm coming from the world of C/C++ and there I'd use & operator to pass objects by reference, but in C# that doesn't seem to work. And that's what I'm asking for help in...

Comment: The result is at the end of this block where for() loop finishes running

Comment: You are mentioning ASP.NET in your post. What is there in context that relates to ASP.NET? Are you printing it on your page? Or does it happen on some event on the page (postback)?

Comment: It happens after the post-back, again, all in one function block so there's no data loss before and after a post-back event. As for ASP.NET, it doesn't make much relevance to this post. I don't know why I put it there. This is mostly C# question... Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't handle reference vs value quite the same as C++.  In C#, everything, even references, are passed by value by default (also: mutable structs are frowned on by several notable c# developers, including stack overflow rep leader Jon Skeet and C# language team lead Eric Lippert).

To get code that does what you're looking for, you do this:

```
class MyStruct { /* all other code is the same, just make it a class */ }

//These are two variables to fill
MyStruct strDest = new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeString, "");
MyStruct nDest = new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeInt, 0);

//Pass variables by reference -- this will work now because "MyStruct" is actually a reference type
MyStruct[] data2Check = {
    strDest, //reference to actual strDest object
    nDest, //reference to actual nDest object
};

//And set them
foreach(var item in data2Check) //foreach will work instead of "for", there are some good reasons to prefer this in C#
{
    if(item.type == MyDataType.MyTypeString)
    {
        item.objDest = "New value"; // no need for a cast
    }
    else if(item.type == MyDataType.MyTypeInt)
    {
        item.objDest = 2;
    }
}
```

But really, you're pulling in some idioms from the C++ world that make no sense at all for C#. Stick with reference types, and go with a generic when types might vary. I'm not sure what exact problem you're trying to solve, or I could give you some more specific guidance on how to express a solution in idiomatic c#

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   public enum MyDataType
    {
        MyTypeString,
        MyTypeInt
    }
    public class MyStruct
    {
        public MyDataType type;
        public Object objDest;

        public MyStruct(MyDataType tType, Object oDest)
        {
            type = tType;
            objDest = oDest;
        }
    }

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           //These are two variables to fill
            MyStruct strDest = new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeString, "");
            MyStruct nDest = new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeInt, 0);

            //Pass variables by reference -- this will work now because "MyStruct" is actually a reference type
            MyStruct[] data2Check = {
    strDest, //reference to actual strDest object
    nDest, //reference to actual nDest object
};

            //And set them
            foreach (var item in data2Check) //foreach will work instead of "for", there are some good reasons to prefer this in C#
            {
                if (item.type == MyDataType.MyTypeString)
                {
                    item.objDest = "New value"; // no need for a cast
                }
                else if (item.type == MyDataType.MyTypeInt)
                {
                    item.objDest = 2;
                }
            }

            Response.Write(strDest.objDest.ToString() + "<br/>" + nDest.objDest.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to review your code first. What I'm trying to do is parse a text and then set a bunch of variables in a class (something like 50 of them) from parameter=value pairs, thus such a construct.

Comment: In that case, idiomatic C# is a to have only a private constructor for the class, and a public static .Create() or .Load() method that takes a reference to a streamreader as an argument and returns a new instance of the object (that static method will be able to call the private constructor). None of the properties of the class should be of type "object", but if you don't know what you're loading in advance you might choose to use a Dictionary<K,V>.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. Sorry. Why can't I declare a member of the MyStruct class/struct as public ref Object objDest?

Comment: The "ref" keyword is only for when you pass to a method. What you're looking to do is sort of shadow a variable with another variable, and it doesn't help that they're a value type. And BTW: now we likely are looking at an asp.net postback issue, as this code (with the small edit I just made) **will** work for preserving references in a Console app.

Comment: Thanks of course, but you're not really helping with those statements. So what you're saying is that it's impossible to do it in C#, right? I guess, one way would be to make a direct assignment and instead of putting it into a loop just copy and paste it 50+ times... Wow, "nice" programming language ))

Comment: Of course it's possible. This code does what you asked about. If you put it in a console app and output the values of strDest.objDest and nDest.objDest after the loop, you'll see "New value" and "2". Whether you're doing yourself a favor using copy/paste for writing your code is another story.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you declare strDest and nDest as members of the page class, and you run the code such you set the new values before a postback and observe them afterward, such that you're working on a new class instance again. That, or you missed part of my code.

Comment: In fact, I just pasted that into a new Web Application project in Visual Studio 2010, used Response.Write( ) to output the results, and I saw "New value" and "2". I'll post the entire code behind file. Look in the top left corner of the page to see the output.

Comment: OK, maybe it works there. So how can I make it work in a web app as well? I also rephrased my original post to give more details...

Comment: My answer now has code that works for a web app. But based on your update text, you would pass the entire class instance to the loop, rather the individual members, and the code in the loop should select the correct property to update. There are two ways to do this: you could run everything through a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) object that matches based on name, or your could use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). You might also be able to use a shortcut with the "dynamic" keyword, depending on what the real code is.

Comment: OK, sorry for all your trouble. But that second code snippet is almost the same as the one above??? I also can't pass the class itself into my for() loop because it defeats the purpose of declaring the 'data2Check' array that defines a relationship between class members and name=value pairs. I don't have time to learn reflection, as well as I don't see how Dictionary can make my life easy in this case... It seems like one big bulky switch() statement is in my future... I'm just glad that I'm not going to deal with this C# any longer. It's one ugly and slow language! (No offence, dude.)

Comment: Minor correction: Ed Maurer is the language development team lead. I'm just a guy on the team.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `strDest` and `nDest` to `MyStruct` constructors, they are passed by value. The compiler generated code is different for a value type `int` and reference type `string`. There is boxing done on the value of `nDest` (that does not affect the `nDest` variable itself). With `string` it is the type immutability (or "copy on write" behaviour) that plays the part.

Comment: Thank you. So is there any way to adjust it so that I can get a reference to those objects and actually set them in my for() loop?

Comment: I would put them both inside a class, declare and instantiate  instance of this class and give this instance to both constructors. Then `MyStruct` will hold the reference to this instance and you can access it in the loop.

Comment: I can't really declare "public ref Object objDest", can I?

Comment: No, you need a reference type holding data values and then change the values owned by an instance of this type.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following you. Can you give a code example? (I also added more details above.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not following what you are trying to do ...and as @JoelCoehoorn (and many others) states, you should try to make your value type (struct) immutable. This is kind of ugly, but here's something that works. If I had a better understanding of what you are trying to do, this would probably be much cleaner - **I do not advocate production use of this example**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo( );
        foo.Set( );

        foreach (var data in foo.data2Check)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", data.type, data.objDest);
        }

        Console.ReadKey( );
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    //These are two variables to fill
    string strDest = "";
    int nDest = 0;
    internal List<MyStruct> data2Check;

    public Foo( )
    {
        data2Check = new List<MyStruct>{
                new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeString, strDest),
                new MyStruct(MyDataType.MyTypeInt, nDest),
            };
    }

    public void Set( )
    {
        //And set them
        for (int i = 0 ; i < data2Check.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (data2Check[i].type == MyDataType.MyTypeString)
            {
                data2Check[i] = new MyStruct(data2Check[i].type, "New value");
            }
            else if (data2Check[i].type == MyDataType.MyTypeInt)
            {
                data2Check[i] = new MyStruct(data2Check[i].type, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum MyDataType
{
    MyTypeString,
    MyTypeInt
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyDataType type;
    public Object objDest;

    public MyStruct(MyDataType tType, Object oDest)
    {
        type = tType;
        objDest = oDest;
    }
}
```

Output:

> MyTypeString = New value
>   MyTypeInt = 2

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn't do it either. I added more detailes in my original question. (And, off topic, Steve Jobs would've flipped that his image was used in an ASP.NET/C# forum...)